# How to drag-and-drop attachments to Mail for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I switched from Outlook to the built-in Mail for Windows 10 app.

To attach a file to an email, I was used to drag it from the desktop to the New Mail window.

In Mail for Windows 10, this doesn't work, the mouse pointer becomes a  prohibited sign.

I have to go to Insert > Attachment, then manually browse for the file.

**Is it possible to active drag-and-drop support for attachments?**

Comment: It sounds like the Mail application does not support the ability to drag and drop files to attach them, if it did, what you are doing would work.

Comment: @Ramhound That's what I feared, but it seems so unbelievable that I thought I'd ask.

Comment: This is both annoying and incredulous. In this day and age.

Comment: TBH, as much as I hate conspiracy-like theories, I have to admit that this Mail app is such a big regression from the built-in mail apps in previous Windows versions, that I am starting to wonder if this is not by design, to push you to buy Outlook (unless this one presents the same regressions in the 2016 version, in which case I would see no explanation whatsoever).

Comment: It's not a desktop app. I've never seen a windows/metro app that supports drag and dropping from desktop apps.

Comment: @Nico It's not Windows 8, I cannot see any difference between the Mail app and any other software I use on Windows 10.

Comment: Don't let windows fool you! Since Windows 10, all apps from the Windows Store look and behave more like desktop applications. They are displayed in a re-sizable window. However, everything inside this window will behave like mobile applications. (animation, bigger buttons, less responsive typing, no drag and drop, etc)

Comment: @Nico I didn't know that, thanks for the explanation! It's a shame though. Drag-and-drop is such a useful feature in a program that is available on a computer with a good old mouse (there are still people actually *working* with computers, right?)

Comment: Windows didn't nail this app, I agree. Luckily there are a lot of other free alternatives.

Comment: @Nico I'm happy to hear your personal favourite apps for mail, as I'm ready for a switch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: It is now possible to drag and drop in mail for Windows 10 ;)

To answer your question: no, you can't use drag 'n drop with Mail for Windows 10. Maybe in a year or so.

You also asked for my personal favorites. It's not allowed to promote services here, but I think it's fair to notify you that you don't *have* to use a desktop application.

Web-based clients (like Gmail) can replace most features of desktop applications. For instance, Gmail supports offline usage, notifications, pop, imap, and drag 'n drop. Given the fact that parties like Microsoft, Mozilla and Google are trying to promote these type of web-based clients, I suggest you look in to it too.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer for now, as it seems to be true that drag-and-drop is not an option at the moment. It's true that StackExchange is not a place for software recommendation. I'll say anyway that I'm trying MailBird, and am quite happy so far, the interface is similar to the Windows 10 Mail app, but it seems much more reliable, and does have features such as drag-n-drop.